# Listview doesn't shows XML parsing data that was fetched using an asynctask

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I am using `XML Parsing` in an `asynctask` to load data in a listview `asyncronously`. When i used `Log.d()` i found that xmlparsing worked properly and shows all the data in log.But when i tried to load it in my listview from async task,the listview shows nothing.Seems like the data isn't loading in the listview at all.

My XMLParsing class

> XMLParser.java

```html
package com.askme.exploretoday;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.util.Log;

public class XMLParser {
 public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;
 
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient+
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
 
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
 
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
    }
 
 
 public Document getDomElement(String xml){
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
 
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
 
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                doc = db.parse(is); 
 
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
                // return DOM
            return doc;
    }
 public String getValue(Element item, String str) {      
     NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
     return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
 }
  
 public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
          Node child;
          if( elem != null){
              if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                  for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                      if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                          return child.getNodeValue();
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
          return "";
   } 

}
```

My List data class that helps to load data as a object and transfer all data in adapter class

> ListData.java

```html
package com.askme.exploretoday;

public class ListData {
  
    String Description;
    String title;
    String details;
    public String getDetails() {
  return details;
 }

 public void setDetails(String details) {
  this.details = details;
 }

 public String getDescription() {
            return Description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
            Description = description;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
            return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
    }

}
```

This is The class where the listview is

> list_activity.java
>
> ```html
> package com.askme.exploretoday;
>
>
> import java.util.ArrayList;
> import java.util.List;
>
> import org.w3c.dom.Document;
> import org.w3c.dom.Element;
> import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
>
>
> import android.app.Activity;
> import android.app.Application;
> import android.app.ProgressDialog;
> import android.content.Context;
> import android.content.Intent;
> import android.os.AsyncTask;
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.util.Log;
> import android.view.View;
> import android.widget.AdapterView;
> import android.widget.ListView;
> import android.widget.TextView;
> import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
>
> public class list_activity extends Activity {
>  ProgressDialog loading;
>  MyBaseAdapter adapter0,adapter1;
>   ListView lvDetail;
>   TextView tv;
>   String xmlLink;
>   Context context = list_activity.this;
>         ArrayList<ListData> myList0 = new ArrayList<ListData>();
>         ArrayList<ListData>myList1= new ArrayList<ListData>();
>
>         @Override
>         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>                 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>                 setContentView(R.layout.caption_list);
>
>                 xmlLink=getIntent().getExtras().getString("newspaper_name");
>                 lvDetail = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvCustomList);
>
>
>           tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.news_caption);
>
>                 try{
>                 new backgroundProcess().execute(adapter0,adapter1);
>                 }catch(Exception e){
>                  tv.setText(e.toString());
>                 }
>
>
>
>
>
>           lvDetail.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
>
>      @Override
>      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
>        View view, int position, long id) {
>       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>       String url=adapter0.getItem(position).getDescription();
>       String c=adapter0.getItem(position).getTitle();
>       String d=adapter0.getItem(position).getDetails();
>       Intent intent=new Intent(context,newsPaper_launcher.class);
>       intent.putExtra("URL", url);
>       intent.putExtra("Title",c);
>       intent.putExtra("Description",d);
>       startActivity(intent);
>      }
>     });
>
>
>
>
>           }
>
>
>      public class backgroundProcess extends AsyncTask<MyBaseAdapter, Integer, MyBaseAdapter>{
>
>    @Override
>    protected void onPreExecute() {
>     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>     loading=new ProgressDialog(context);
>           loading.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
>           loading.setMessage("Please wait...");
>           loading.setIndeterminate(true);
>           loading.setCancelable(true);
>           loading.show();
>
>    }
>    @Override
>    protected MyBaseAdapter doInBackground(MyBaseAdapter... adapterArray) {
>     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>
>     // insert fake data into the list before setting the adapter
>                 // otherwise it will generate NullPointerException  - Obviously
>
>                 ListData ld = new ListData();
>                 ld.setTitle("fakeData");
>                 ld.setDescription("fakeData");
>                 ld.setDetails("fake Data");
>                 myList0.add(ld);
>                 myList1.add(ld);
>
>
>
>                 adapterArray[0]=new MyBaseAdapter(context, myList0);
>     adapter0=new MyBaseAdapter(context, myList0);
>           String title,address,details;
>              XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
>              String xml = null;
>              try{
>               xml=parser.getXmlFromUrl(xmlLink);
> //              xml=parser.getXmlFromUrl("http:/newagebd.net/feed/");
> //              xml=parser.getXmlFromUrl("http://www.ittefaq.com.bd/rss.xml");
> //                xml= parser.getXmlFromUrl("http://bdnews24.com/?widgetName=rssfeed&widgetId=1150&getXmlFeed=true"); // getting XML
> //             xml=parser.getXmlFromUrl("http://thebangladeshtoday.com/feed/");
> //             xml=parser.getXmlFromUrl("http://bangla.bdnews24.com/?widgetName=rssfeed&widgetId=1151&getXmlFeed=true");
> //             xml=parser.getXmlFromUrl("http://www.amardeshonline.com/pages/rss");
>              }catch(Exception e)
>              {
>               tv.setText(e.toString());
>              }
>     Element cap,url,news;
>     ListData temp;
>                 Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
>                 NodeList caption=doc.getElementsByTagName("title");
>                 NodeList link = doc.getElementsByTagName("link");
>                 NodeList fullNews=doc.getElementsByTagName("description");
>                  for (int i = 2; i < link.getLength(); i++) {
>                     cap = (Element) caption.item(i);
>                     url = (Element) link.item(i);
>                     news=(Element) fullNews.item(i);
>                    title = parser.getValue(cap, "title");
>                    address = parser.getValue(url, "link");
>                    details=parser.getValue(news, "description");
>       Log.i("INFO Check",title+"\n"+address+"\n"+details);
>       temp = new ListData();
>                    temp.setTitle(title);
>                    temp.setDescription(address);
>                    temp.setDetails(details);
>                    myList0.add(temp);
>                 }
>
>                 myList0.remove(0);
>
>                 adapter0.notifyDataSetChanged();
>                 adapterArray[0].notifyDataSetChanged();
>
>     return adapterArray[0];
>
>    }
>                 @Override
>        protected void onPostExecute(MyBaseAdapter result) {
>         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>                  loading.cancel();
>         lvDetail.setAdapter(adapter0);
> //        super.onPostExecute(result);
>        }
>
>    }
>
>
>
> }
> ```

My BaseAdapter class that loads the data in the listview

> MyBaseAdapter.java

```html
package com.askme.exploretoday;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
 
public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        
        ArrayList<ListData> myList = new ArrayList<ListData>();
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        Context context;
        public MyBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListData> myList) {
                this.myList = myList;
                this.context = context;
                inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);        // only context can also be used
        }
 
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
                return myList.size();
        }
 
        @Override
        public ListData getItem(int position) {
                return myList.get(position);
        }
 
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
                return 0;
        }
 
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                MyViewHolder mViewHolder;
                
                if(convertView == null) {
                        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                        mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder();
                        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
                } else {
                        mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }
                
                
                mViewHolder.tvTitle = detail(convertView, R.id.tvTitle, myList.get(position).getTitle());
                 if(mViewHolder.tvTitle.toString().isEmpty())
                  mViewHolder.tvTitle.setText("ERROR");
                return convertView;
        }
        
        // or you can try better way
        private TextView detail(View v, int resId, String text) {
                TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(resId);
                tv.setText(text);
                return tv;
        }
        
        
        private class MyViewHolder {
                TextView tvTitle;
        }
 
}
```

Comment: If you are expecting us to debug all of that, you could at least format it correctly and provide your own research on the causes of the problem from using the debugger yourself. See [how to debug a small program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Even better, provide an [MCVE] and the question could be answered almost immediately.

Comment: I already told that the problem is in list_activity.java class inside the async task...The rest of the code is just for understanding. and i don't know what you meant by formatting.Each code i provided is in a separate snippet.Each snippet even has a title that clearly describe what is the purpose of this class.what more to do here?

Comment: and i also said that it's not about showing logcat because the xmlparser loads data properly which was checked using logcat,but can't load it in listview,seems like the adapter for listview is declared wrongly.that's what was my concern.

Comment: Okay that's fine. I'm just trying to help you ask better received questions. I started trying to look through your code but was distracted by the comments and the indentation. It can easily be fixed with Ctrl-Alt L in your IDE. If the other code is irrelevant, you can minify it so it is easier for someone else to debug.

Comment: @DavidRawson thanks for your help. i will modify it soon :)

Comment: Actually, the other code is relevant because you are using `AsyncTask` incorrectly. Spend some more time reading the documentation for that - you shouldn't have to be saving to class fields all , especially ones that are duplicated in an array